# Regex in java to match every "line begin" and replace

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to make a regexp to replace line beginnings for a line begin plus a \t. 
The goal ir to learn regular expressions and how to use the matcher class.
Here is my code till now:

```
        StringBuilder ambe = new StringBuilder();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^\\s*\\w*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pop.toString());

    ambiente.append("Ambe: [\n");

    ambiente.append(matcher.replaceAll("\t$1"));

    ambiente.append("]\n");

    return ambiente.toString();
```

Inside pop there is several \n to break lines. but this code is just replacing the first line.
Any advice?

Comment: See here:
 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [multline flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) in your regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)(^\\s*\\w*)");
```

OR

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^\\s*\\w*)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```